# how to remove duplicate string values from multimap

Tags: c++, unique, multimap

I've got a `std::multimap` that has multiple entries with the same key and value and I want to remove all duplicate values, only keeping the one with the highest index.
So far I've got something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include<iterator>
#include <map>


int main(void)
{

    std::multimap<double, std::string> m;

    m.insert(std::pair<double,std::string>(79.43567,"ARH1265"));
    m.insert(std::pair<double,std::string>(82.96567,"ARH1265"));
    m.insert(std::pair<double,std::string>(94.03261,"TE5748"));
    m.insert(std::pair<double,std::string>(73.53961,"TE5748"));
    m.insert(std::pair<double,std::string>(93.43567,"CRP5285"));

    std::cout << "size: " << m.size() << std::endl;

    std::multimap<double, std::string>::iterator it;
    for (it = m.begin(); i!=m.end(); i++) {
        // ???
    }
}
```

and I'll want to end up with a map with three entries in the map:

```
82.96567, ARH1265
94.03261, TE5748
93.43567, CRP5285
```

Comment: why do you use a multimap in the first place? Would a map / unordered_map be better?

Comment: @user463035818 because in the end I need unique items with the highest score/index and a multimap gives me this automatically w/o the need to order. There however is a possibility, that there will be two of the same indexes present.

Comment: ah sorry, misread. You want to erase those with same value (not same key)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can, replace the `std::multimap` by a `std::map` or a `std::unordered_map`, and reverse the key and values. (key = `string` and value = `double`).

When inserting, check if the value you want to insert is bigger than the value in the map, if not, don't insert.

If you can't replace the multimap, you can use the approach above with a temporary map, clear the multimap and insert the contents of the temporary map back into the multimap.

Answer (score 1):

```
{
    std::unordered_set<std::string> already_seen;
    for (it = m.begin(); i!=m.end(); i++) {
        if (already_seen.find(it->second) != already_seen.end())
             m.erase(it);
        else
            already_seen.insert(it->second);
    }
}
```

You can use also `std::remove_if` from the stl with a lambda function, if you are up for experimenting

Comment: This solution will work, but it is going to get very slow for anything but a small number of elements. (O(N²)) A vector is not an appropriate data structure for this.

Comment: This code has undefined behavior.  `m.erase(it)` invalidates `it`